# При запуске эмулятора в Android Studio на Ubuntu появляется ошибка

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android-studio, android-emulator

Ошибка `ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration` при запуске эмулятора в android studio на ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Попробуйте Генимоушн.

Comment: Человек, пишущий такое, что движет тобой? Текста ошибки ты не читал, иначе понял бы, в чем проблема. Решил всех проинформировать? Никому не интересно, что у тебя ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Все довольно просто:

1. Копируем текст ошибки и вставляем в поисковую строку [Google](https://www.google.ru/webhp?hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwl_yLmeXmAhUMr4sKHZE5DCUQPAgH).
2. Первый [результат](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration) понятное дело enSO.
3. Берем самый топовый ответ, так как он вероятнее всего рабочий и смотрим что там написано.

А написано там вот что:

1. Откройте SDK Manager (в Android Studio выберите «Инструменты»> «Android»> «SDK Manager») и загрузите Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (установщик HAXM), если у вас его нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Дальше идем в папку по адресу:
   `C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\` и запускаем файл `intelhaxm-android.exe`. Если будут ошибки то нужно в биосе включить поддержку виртуализации.
3. Перезагружаем студию и вуаля - все работает!!!

Как видите все довольно просто и понятно :) Удачи :)

### UPDATE

Если уж совсем будет сложно и эмулятор не поднимется, то поставьте как вам советовали в комментариях Genymotion. Он прекрасно работает и устанавливается на линуксе. Но мне кажется что если проблема в биосе то он тоже будет работать плохо (или вообще не будет).